# Define unique_ptr owned by base class

Tags: c++

I have two classes that are doing something very similar, however, the derived class needs to have a slightly different object that is owned by the base class. The difference is in how we construct this object.

```
class Object { public: Object(std::string someString, ...); .... };

class Base
{
public:
  Base(int a) : value(a), object(std::make_unique<Object>("Base", ... )) {}
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  ...
protected:
  int value;
  std::unique_ptr<Object> object;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived(int a) : Base(a) { object = std::make_unique<Object>("Derived", ... ); }
  ~Derived() override = default;
};

void fun()
{
  Derived d(42);
}
```

Based on the code given, I am initializing the member variable "object" twice. First in the base class and then again in the derived class. How do I do this differently? Is there a different design (not inheritance?) or some different structuring that would work? I could just send in the different initialization variables into the Base class constructor and/or create a different constructor altogether in the Base class, but is there any other way?

Comment: Make `object` a parameter of the base class constructor then you can pass it in from the derived class

Comment: And the fancy name for that is "dependency injection."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it is to provide a `protected` constructor in `Base` which can be used by both `Base` and `Derived`. The `public` constructor in `Base` would just delegate the work of creating the `Object` to that constructor.

Example:

```cpp
class Base {
protected:
    Base(int a, std::string str)
        : value(a), object(std::make_unique<Object>(std::move(str))) {}

public:
    Base(int a) : Base(a, "Base") {} // delegate to the protected ctor
    virtual ~Base() = default;

private:
    int value;
    std::unique_ptr<Object> object;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int a) : Base(a, "Derived") {} // use the protected Base ctor
    ~Derived() override = default;
};
```